Tendril package used to generate the tendril plot gives error
I am trying to generate the tendril plot using the Tendril package, however I am unable to generate the plot and results in error. I tried changing the function argument values but no success. Please help me resolve the issue
I used the adae data from the Tplyr package
library(Tendril)
library(Tplyr)

adae <- Tplyr::tplyr_adae %>% filter(SAFFL=='Y' & TRTAN %in% c(0, 54)) %>% select(USUBJID, TRTA, ASTDY, AEDECOD) %>% 
  arrange(USUBJID, TRTA, AEDECOD, ASTDY) %>% filter(ASTDY>0)

names(adae) <- tolower(names(adae))


SubjList <- adae %>% select(usubjid, trta)

data <- Tendril(mydata = adae,
                rotations = 70,
                AEfreqThreshold = 1,
                Tag = "Comment",
                Treatments = c("Placebo", "Xanomeline Low Dose"),
                Unique.Subject.Identifier = "usubjid",
                Terms = "aedecod",
                Treat = "trta",
                StartDay = "astdy",
                SubjList = SubjList,
                SubjList.subject = "usubjid",
                SubjList.treatment = "trta",
                suppress_warnings = TRUE
)


res <- plot(data, coloring = "Terms")

Error
Error in .validate_tendril_results(tab) :
No sample with the defined frequency threshold
In addition: Warning messages:
1: In xtfrm.data.frame(x) : cannot xtfrm data frames
2: In xtfrm.data.frame(x) : cannot xtfrm data frames
